# foreach statement creating an invalid arguments

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to pass my sql array results to foreach statement so that i can access the columns from table in another file. Just a small mistake i am doing and getting an invalid arguments pass to foreach statament error.
Here is my code:
dashboard.php

```
include('includes/dashboard.inc');    
$user_id=$_SESSION['sessad']['user']['dsnr'];
$widgets = array(); 
$sql="SELECT dashboard_widget.name,dashboard_widget.id,dashboard_widget_users.position,dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget
FROM dashboard_widget_users
INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.ID
WHERE dsnr_yw_user =".$user_id."
ORDER BY position";
$sql_results=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_results))
{
    $widgets[] = $row;  
}
```

dashboard.inc.php

```
$widgets=$_POST['widgets'];
foreach ($widgets as $key => $val) 
{
    $name = $val['name'];
    $id=$val['id'];
    $page['content'] .= '
    <div id=recordsArray_'.$name.'>
    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="'.$name.'">
            </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </div>';
}
```

Comment: can you show the output result ?

Comment: You're passing the entire $row array into the new arry when it isn't necessary. Just call the items out of the array $row['name'] as you need them in the loop.

Comment: but without storing them how can i use it into dashboard.inc .php file ?

Comment: if these aren't function body-s, just move your include 'dashboard.inc.php'; after your while loop

Comment: In dashboard.inc.php file when i echo var_dump($widgets) then it is showing null :(

Comment: How are you posting the variable back to your dashboard.inc.php?

Comment: Can we have a look at the output of $row.??

Comment: yes its array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(9) "FAHRZEUGE" ["name"]=> string(9) "FAHRZEUGE" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" ["position"]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "1" ["dsnr_dashboard_widget"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(4) "NEWS" ["name"]=> string(4) "NEWS" [1]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "1" ["position"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "2" ["dsnr_dashboard_widget"]=> string(1) "2" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your code your code is'n Object oriented and you aren't using functions.

So when you `include('includes/dashboard.inc');` in your first line, your code is running but $widgets is null, because interpretator exeecutes the code when including, so **move your include statement after your while loop**, and your `$widgets` variable should not be a null, and you'll se the html result.

**EDIT: and remove this line `$widgets=$_POST['widgets'];` from widgets.inc.php**

> NOTE: I just predict what you want to do from your codes, so as I see
>   you don't need for $_POST['widgets'] you just want to print widgets
>   from database, otherwise if isn't and I'm wrong, please clarify your
>   question in comments.

**EDIT 2**

```
   $user_id=$_SESSION['sessad']['user']['dsnr'];
    $widgets = array(); 
    $sql="SELECT dashboard_widget.name,dashboard_widget.id,dashboard_widget_users.position,dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget
    FROM dashboard_widget_users
    INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.ID
    WHERE dsnr_yw_user =".$user_id."
    ORDER BY position";
    $sql_results=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_results))
    {
        $widgets[] = $row;  
    }
include('includes/dashboard.inc');
```

and widgets.inc.php

```
foreach ($widgets as $key => $val) 
{
    $name = $val['name'];
    $id=$val['id'];
    $page['content'] .= '
    <div id=recordsArray_'.$name.'>
    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="'.$name.'">
            </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </div>';
}
```

Comment: no man still in dashboard.inc.php when i try to var_dump($widgets) it showing null..but in dashboard.php when i try to do var_dump($widgets) it showing my results. So i am not able to pass my dashboard.php file results to dashboard.inc.php and i have included include('includes/dashboard.inc'); in the first line but still...

Comment: ok and if i dont use $widgets=$_POST['widgets']; in dashboard.inc.php file then how can call my table column using foreach loop ?

Comment: $_POST is array which is data sent by user or some other programs via http protocol with POST method, for reading data from your query you don't need for $_POST.